# Multiple Table for Single Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I Have One *Message* Model and both Admin and User can create a message. But for Admin and User have separate model called *Admin* and *User*.

Message model have a column called 'created_by' and which stores creator's id. Now the question is how can I make relationship  with Message and creator. I need to get the creators details from 'Admin' model or from 'User' Model.

Currently I'm using a method inside *Message* model as below.

```
public function creator(){
    if(User::find($this->created_by)){
      return User::find($this->created_by);
    }else{
      return Admin::find($this->created_by);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't support Eager Loading feature in Laravel.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use polymorphic relationship https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use polymorphic relationship in this case. As stated in [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)

> A polymorphic relationship allows the target model to belong to more than one type of model using a single association.

By doing this, you can get messages from both **Admin** and **User** models.

Define the following method in **Message** model.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model

{
    /**
     * Get the owning messageable model.
     */
    public function messageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

And add following columns in the migration file:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('messageable_id');
$table->string('messageable_type');
```

Then, define the below method in **Admin** model.

```
class Admin extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the admin's messages.
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Message', 'messageable');
    }
}
```

And in **User** model.

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the user's messages.
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Message', 'messageable');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also a great answer but i feel mutators are the better solution when it comes to making choices on secondary queries.  This just moves the condition to a later spot in the application request most likely near the view or controller but the condition to choose admin or user will always be there mutators help lazy load that condition better.

Comment: @jgetner pay attention to the number of query that must be performed to save a record in case of using mutator.

Comment: You are correct when using a mutator what i meant was accessors in laravel they are only preformed on the result and should have no impact on your saves. I updated my answer to reflect this.  But both should work fine this just comes down to where you need to access the user and how that looks and what makes the most sense for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for support,
is I need to add any column to existing 'Message' Table?

Comment: @ShihabEK I updated the answer to have database table details too.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has Accessor they are great for this sort of thing.  In your model add a method such as below. this will take the created by id and search up the admin or user and then return those results.   So now when you make your message query you just access the user such as $message->created_by->username;  You can learn more about mutators in here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

```
 public function getCreatedByAttribute($value)
 {
    $user = User::where('id', $value)->first();
    if(!is_null($user)){
        return $user;
    }

    $admin = Admin::where('id', $value)->first();
    if(!is_null($admin)){
        return $admin;
    }

   return null;

 }
```